# Error handling image src from RSS feed

Tags: javascript, jquery, rss

I'm using this [PaRSS jQuery plugin](http://www.bradwestness.com/parss-a-jquery-rss-feed-plugin,413) to pull images from a bundle of RSS feeds. Now, some of the image matches returned are just a word (but image src can sometimes be found elsewhere in the feed).

How would I go about writing an error handler for this that:

- checks against JPG, PNG, GIF
- if the above is false, finds the correct src path somewhere else in the RSS feed
- if an image is still not found, show a dummy image

This is the function that runs a match for images:

```
function getImageFromContent(content) {
      var img = content.match(/<img[^>+]*>/i);
      if(img) {
        var source = img[0].match(/src="[^"+]*"/i),
        alt = img[0].match(/alt="[^"+]*"/i);
        return "<img " + source + " " + alt + " />";
      }
      return false;
    }
```

A few hints as to how I might go about this, would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The regexp looks a little strange - shouldn't it be just `/src="[^"]*"/` (i.e. no plus sign in the character class)?

Comment: Also, if you could post an example of the kind of RSS content, you need parsed - it'd be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to check whether an image's src url ends in jpg, png or gif, you can try matching the `<img>` tag returned by `getImageFromContent()`

```
var img = getImageFromContent(content);
var src = img.match(/src="([^"?]*)("|\?)/i)
var isProperUrl = !!src[1].match(/\.(jpg|png|gif)$/i);
```

`isProperUrl` will be true if the src ends with jpg, png, or gif.

Comment: In this case simply replacing `var img = content.match(/<img[^>+]*>/i);` with your reg exp `(/src="([^"?]*)("|\?)/i)` worked and it now collects all images. Thanks!